# Кастомный ProgressBar android

Tags: java, android, android-customview

Хочу сделать `ProgressBar` который состоит из 5-ти звезд. Фон у этих звезд серый  и при увеличении прогресса эти звезды должны заполнятся золотым цветом. Пока что у меня получилось просто отрисовать 5 звезд одного цвета.

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
public class StartView extends ViewGroup {

    private int progress  = 0;

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();


    public StartView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public StartView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public StartView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float mid = getWidth() / 2;
        float min = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
        float fat = min / 17;
        float half = min / 2;
        float margin = half/2;
        mid = mid - half;



        float left = mid  - (half+margin);
        float start = left - (half+margin);
        float right = mid +(half+margin);
        float end = right + (half+margin);


        //mid
        drawStart(canvas,fat,mid,half);

        //to left mid
        drawStart(canvas,fat,left,half);

        drawStart(canvas,fat,start,half);

        //to right mid
        drawStart(canvas,fat,right,half);

        drawStart(canvas,fat,end,half);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void drawStart(Canvas canvas, float fat, float mid , float half){
        paint.setStrokeWidth(fat);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.hintIconColorCommon));

        // top left
        path.moveTo(mid + half * 0.5f, half * 0.84f);
        // top right
        path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.5f, half * 0.84f);
        // bottom left
        path.lineTo(mid + half * 0.68f, half * 1.45f);
        // top tip
        path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.0f, half * 0.5f);
        // bottom right
        path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.32f, half * 1.45f);
        // top left
        path.lineTo(mid + half * 0.5f, half * 0.84f);

        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

и результат вот такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример того что мне нужно получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть предположение что можно просто отрисовать прогресс (золотого цвета) как прямоугольник, а сверху него прозрачные звезды,думаю надо копать куда то в сторону масок, но это не точно.

Вобщем вопрос состоит в том, как можно реализовать нужный мне функционал?

Comment: а вы пробовали просто проставить свой drawable для прогресса?

Comment: Не до конца понимаю как реализовать то о чем вы говорите, учитывая т о что звезды могут быть заполнены лишь частично, если у вас идея как это сделать, можете оформить ответ, в принципе, мне такой вариант подходит, т.к. он скорее всего менее затратный получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Серый фон, поверх него ProgressBar золотого цвета, поверх него SVG изображение белого цвета с вырезами под звезды. Всё это во `FrameLayout`(Про него можно почитать [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/framelayout.php)).

Comment: ужос.. попроще никак?

Comment: В чем именно сложность? По сути это обычный ProgressBar с серым фоном и желтым цветом.

Comment: Я не говорю что это сложно, имелось в виду что вместо одного компонента появляется три.